# ggplot2 bar chart with lines inside bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I'm making a plot in which I have a 3x3 grid obtained from `facet_wrap`. Eight out of nine plots use `geom_violin` while the remaining plot is made using `geom_bar`. After finding some helpful answers here on the site, I got this all working. The problem that I have is that when I use `fill = "white, color = "black"` for my bar chart, it draws these lines *inside* the bars.

Here is some example code and figures.

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- 100
tib <- tibble(value = c(rnorm(n, mean = 100, sd = 10), rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = (1:4)/4)),
              variable = rep(c("IQ", "Sex"), each = n),
              year = factor(rep(2012:2015, n/2)))
ggplot(tib, aes(x = year, y = value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_violin(data = filter(tib, variable == "IQ")) +
  geom_bar(data = filter(tib, variable == "Sex"), stat = "identity", 
           color = "black", fill = "white")
```

[image]

Now to my question: how do I get rid of these lines inside the bars? I just want it to be white with black borders. I've been experimenting a lot with various configurations, and I can manage to get rid of the lines but at the expense of screwing the facet up. I'm fairly certain it's got to do with the stat, but I'm at a loss trying to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you really want to use a facet ? Since the axes are really different, it would be easier to make the 2 plots separately, and plot them together using e.g. `library(cowplot)'

Comment: @FlorianGD It makes it simple to get all the plots together, with common titles and everything. They all share the same x axis, too. But maybe I need to check out `cowplot`.

Comment: the black bars are there because it automatically stacks the values from tib$value. You can use position_dodge or first average over values per year. It is important to know what you want to get out first, the ratio of values?

Comment: @timfaber I want the plot I have included, but without the borders inside the bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest summarizing the data within the barplot:

```
ggplot(tib, aes(x = year, y = value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_violin(data = filter(tib, variable == "IQ")) +
  geom_bar(data = tib %>%
             group_by(year,variable) %>%
             summarise(value=sum(value)) %>%
             filter(variable == "Sex"),
           stat = "identity", 
           color = "black",
           fill = "white")
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is a good way to represent the data, with the y-axes of the different panels representing very different things, but accept that your example might not match your actual use case. Making separate plots and then using `gridExtra::grid.arrange`, or `cowplot::plot_grid` is probably a better solution.

But if you want to do this

```
ggplot(tib, aes(x = year, y = value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_violin(data = filter(tib, variable == "IQ")) +
  geom_col(data = filter(tib, variable == "Sex") %>%
                  group_by(year, variable) %>% 
                  summarise(value = sum(value)), 
    fill = "white", colour = "black")
```

Using `geom_col` rather than `geom_bar` so I don't need to use `stat = identity`.

Comment: I will definitely look into cowplot (I used gridExtra before, but I thought it was a little bit complicated for my objective here--especially since I could do the plot with the borders). (CMichael was a couple of minutes faster, which is why I accepted their answer.)

Comment: Love how dplyr yields almost the same code from independent coders.